# Sum of output values

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of objects called `Gear`. Each object has attributes of `String Name`, `String Type`, `Int rateOfFire` and `Int Damage`. I also have a function that calculates damage per second (DPS) for each weapon by multiplying damage by `rateOfFire`. The problem I'm having is that this function prints off the damage of each weapon in a list, but i would also like the total DPS of all weapons in the list.

This is my method:

```
public static void getDPS()

    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Gear.size(); i++) 
        {
        int damage =  Gear.get(i).damage;
        int fireRate = Gear.get(i).fireRate;
        int DPS =(damage*fireRate)/60;
        System.out.println("DPS for weapon " + i+1 + " is: " +DPS);
        System.out.println("Total DPS= " );
        }
    }
```

And this is my output:

```
DPS for weapon 01 is: 10

Total DPS= 


DPS for weapon 11 is: 12

Total DPS=
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am only a novice to programming!

Comment: You will also want to change `"..." + i+1 + "..."` into `"..." + (i+1) + "..."` : without the parenthesis since the operators have the same order of precedence, `"..."+i` is applied first, and the `1` is concatenated as string after

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 0;//define a new variable

for (int i = 0; i < Gear.size(); i++) 
{
    int damage =  Gear.get(i).damage;
    int fireRate = Gear.get(i).fireRate;
    int DPS =(damage*fireRate)/60;
    total += DPS; // add to total var.
    System.out.println("DPS for weapon " + i+1 + " is: " +DPS);
}

System.out.println("Total DPS= " + total);//print the total outside the loop
```

Also as @Aaron mentioned in the comment wrap `i+1` using parenthesis `(i+1)` to avoid `String` concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a total DPS variable before the loop, add the DPS of the current weapon in the loop, then print the total .

```
int totalDPS = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Gear.size(); i++) 
    {
    int damage =  Gear.get(i).damage;
    int fireRate = Gear.get(i).fireRate;
    int DPS =(damage*fireRate)/60;
    totalDPS += DPS; // add current DPS to total
    System.out.println("DPS for weapon " + i+1 + " is: " +DPS);
    System.out.println("Total DPS= " + totalDPS );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is also a "streamy" solution ...

```
class Gear {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int rateOfFire;
    private int damage;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

Create a test List:

```
List<Gear> gears = new ArrayList<>();
gears.add(new Gear("a", "a", 10, 10));
gears.add(new Gear("b", "b", 5, 5));
```

Print DPS per `Gear` and total DPS:

```
gears.forEach(x -> 
  System.out.println("dps = " + x.getDamage() * x.getRateOfFire()));
System.out.println("Total dps = " + 
  gears.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.getDamage() * x.getRateOfFire()).sum());
```

Which prints:

```
dps = 100
dps = 25
Total dps = 125
```